# Failing on JSON Body Data Posting in Jmeter

Tags: json, post, jmeter

I have the following situation:

I have a **POST** request having Content encoding defined as **utf-8**

It is posting some **JSON** data, however I did not correlated any of them in previous responses. The JSON data looks like the following:

```
["Diagnosis","Gender","MaritalStatus","PCC","CONNECTION_SOURCE_STATUS","CONNECTION_TARGET_STATUS","BED_TYPE","SECURITY_QUESTION","ADMIT_TYPE","DECLINE_REASON","HH_DECLINE_REASON","SMS_VENDOR_DOMAIN"]
```

The request gets failed and no exact reason is located, but I see it has returned the Response code: **403** which is Forbidden.

I'm stuck at this point. How could I resolve this issue, please advise.

[image]

Comment: Please add HTTP Authorization header and validate it again.

Comment: Added the HTTP Authorization Manager. But no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved. The Response Code **403 (Forbidden)** was appearing because of **X-CSRF-TOKEN** parameter was being passed in Request Header.

I extracted the X-CSRF-TOKEN through **Regular Expression Extractor** Post-Processor and passed it on the subsequent requests.

Thanks